# Reformatting python dictionaries within a List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python List containing dictionaries like below

```
[{'mad phony': {'null': 49, 'valid': 10, 'invalid': 10}, 'base_url': 'https://madphony.org/'}, {'nashvilly': {'null': 18, 'valid': 5, 'invalid': 4}, 'base_url': 'https://www.nashvilly.org/'}]
```

I want this data to be formatted like

```
[{"org":"mad phony", "base_url": "https://madphony.org/", "pend_val":49, "val":20},
{"org":"nashvilly", "base_url": "https://www.nashvilly.org/", "pend_val":18, "val":9}]
```

Is there an efficient manner to reformat like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely not the most efficient way but it is clear and standard,

```
in_data = [{'mad phony': {'null': 49, 'valid': 10, 'invalid': 10}, 'base_url': 'https://madphony.org/'}, {'nashvilly': {'null': 18, 'valid': 5, 'invalid': 4}, 'base_url': 'https://www.nashvilly.org/'}]

out_data = []
for dict_i in in_data:
    temp_dict = {}
    # Process each dictionary in the list
    for key, value in dict_i.items():
        # Different processing for the URL part
        if 'base_url' in key:
            temp_dict[key] = value
        else:
            temp_dict['org'] = key
            temp_dict['pend_val'] = value['null']
            temp_dict['val'] = value['valid'] + value['invalid']
    out_data.append(temp_dict)
```

The code iterates through the input list and using some assumptions on the structure of its elements constructs the output.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. Please upvote the question too